# Can any group be realized as the multiplicative group of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ring with Z as its group of units?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75192/ring-with-z-as-its-group-of-units)

Given a group $G$, does there always exist a ring $R$ such that $R^\times \cong G$? I feel like this isn't true but that's just a hunch. One of my friends asked me this yesterday and we couldn't come up with an answer so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Does the group ring $F_2[G]$ work?

Comment: This came up before. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75192/ring-with-z-as-its-group-of-units

Comment: And Jesse Elliot's comment says that $F_2[G]$ does not work.

Comment: When $|G|$ is finite and odd, then it must be the direct product of cyclic groups of order $2^k-1$ for various $k$; in other words, you only have to worry about the groups coming from $R=GF(2^{n_1})\times GF(2^{n_2})\times\cdots$.

Comment: Nice  question!